# Не получается отключить dual point stick Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS ноутбук Dell

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dell

Ребята, доброго времени суток. Работаю на ноутбуке Dell в котором встроен point stick.
[image: Аналог тачпада]

В связи с тем, что ноутбук достаточно старый, данная приспособа (pointing stick) стал глючить управляя курсором по своему усмотрению.

На ноутбуке стоит ОС Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. Ранее тоже стояла убунту, но не вспомню какая точно версия. И вопрос с отключением стика решался в одну команду xinput set-int-prop "id" 'Device Enabled' 8 0.

Сейчас же загвоздка заключается в том, что по выполнению команды xinput вообще не видит подключенное устройство point stick.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тем не мение в файле bus/proc/input/devices он отображается со всем своим описанием.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, может кто то сталкивался с подобным? И у кого какие могут быть предположения на этот счет? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Судя по "xwayland", у вас больше не иксы, и пользовать привычные команды типа xinput теперь бесполезно. Придётся или искать управление устройствами ввода в Wayland (есть ли оно, я не в курсе), или переключаться в сессию с иксами

Comment: Окей. сейчас попробую в эту степь покопать. По результатам внесу изминения в свой вопрос. Спасибо за инфу, есть хоть направление в котором необходимо думать)